# Get mosaic-like screenshot using IMGKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit, imgkit

Here I want to take a screenshot of an external url, and I use IMGkit with CarrierWave.

```
  #Class Micropost
  after_create :take_snapshot     
  def take_snapshot
    file = Tempfile.new(["template_#{self.id.to_s}", 'jpg'], 'tmp', :encoding => 'ascii-8bit')
    file.write(IMGKit.new(self.external_url).to_jpg)
    file.flush
    self.snapshot = file
    self.save
    file.unlink
  end
```

and the screenshot get generated is.....
[image]

So whats wrong with it?

Comment: I just create a Rails app and was able to create a screenshot without any problem. What version of wkhtmltoimage did you install? Mine installed `0.10.0 rc2`

Comment: wkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-installer.exe  for windows

Comment: OK, soooo sorry to say, but your problem is either: 1) on windows or 2) try to get the 0.10.0 rc2 installed.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I'm having trouble in push it to heroku, do you have any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975269/permission-denied-when-using-imgkit-on-heroku-do-we-need-to-precompile-binary-o

Comment: @JesseWolgamott and is there any examples that I can follow? I changed to  0.10.0 rc2 but still get the mosaic looking

Comment: use https://github.com/bradphelan/wkhtmltopdf-heroku

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, but in IMGKIT, it requires `wkhtmltoimage`, which this gem does not provide

Comment: Ahh yes, please follow the heroku instructions on https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit and/or https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit/issues/31